# Can't parse url from gmail using imaplib

Tags: python, gmail-imap, imaplib

I 'am using imaplib(python) to login into gmail inbox and searching for appropriate messages.
But when I'am printing those message, links inside the message body seems to be broken.
With '3D' appended randomly.

Comment: use urlparse library.

Comment: You probably aren't decoding the message body properly.

Comment: You can try to use high level lib: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Answer (score 2):

'3D' is the hexadecimal encoding of '='. So the problem is that you aren't properly decoding the email, which can be done using python's `email` module and `message.get_payload(decode=True)`.

Here's a short snippet:

```
import imaplib, email
imap_server = "imap.aol.com" #maybe this would be imap.gmail.com for gmail?
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server, 993)
conn.login(username, password)
conn.select()
resp, data = conn.uid('FETCH', '1:*' , '(RFC822)')
raw = data[0][1].strip()
message = email.message_from_string(raw)

decoded = message.get_payload(decode=True) #this will be the decoded body of the email message
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [Imbox](https://github.com/martinrusev/imbox)

Because `imaplib` is a very excessive low level library and returns results which are hard to work with

**Installation**

`pip install imbox`

**Usage**

```
from imbox import Imbox

with Imbox('imap.gmail.com',
        username='username',
        password='password',
        ssl=True,
        ssl_context=None,
        starttls=False) as imbox:

    all_inbox_messages = imbox.messages()
    for uid, message in all_inbox_messages:
        message.sent_from
        message.sent_to
        message.subject
        message.headers
        message.message_id
        message.date
        message.body.plain
        message.body.html
        message.attachments
```